# Can't put an image as background on css

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to put an image as background, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Below you will find my `HTML` and `CSS`. The name of the image is `Background` and its size is `1280*720`.

The `HTML`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
              <title></title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">


        </head>
        <body >

            <header>

            </header>






            <footer></footer> 

        </body>      

    </html>
```

The `CSS`:

```
body {
background: url("C:\Users\pro tech\Desktop\site web\Nouveau dossier: background.jpeg") no-repeat;

background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: The URL of the image looks very wrong; can you show the file structure for your project?

Comment: @Deepak I've tried to do it on a body with more content but still the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The image url should be relative to your css file and not your desktop. Or in your case relative to the html file because you have inline css.

The url is way off.

It should be something like...

background: url("/images/background.jpeg")

Answer (score 1):

The url of the background image needs to begin where that CSS file is located. If you need to go back a folder, you use `../`, which leads me to my next thing: make sure you are using forward slashes and not back slashes.

Example: If you have your CSS file on your desktop right now, your path would look like this: 
`url("site%20web/Nouveau%20dossier/background.jpeg");`

Answer (score 0):

maybe because there is blank space on the url link?
try to replace the blank url with %20

```
body {
background: url("C:\Users\pro%20tech\Desktop\site%20web\Nouveau dossier\background.jpeg") no-repeat;

background-size: cover;
}
```

or just remove the detail URL, and just use image file name if the image is in the same folder as html and css

```
body {
background: url("background.jpeg") no-repeat;

background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in the same folder where you have your index and Css and then add the css with the new location of the file:

for exemple:

```
body {
background : URL("./image.jpeg") no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add some height or content to the body. for now height is 0px so background image is not showing